# Convergence of $\left( \frac{1}{1} \right)^2+\left( \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3} \right)^2+\cdots$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Does the following series converge? If yes, what is its value in simplest form?

$$\left( \frac{1}{1} \right)^2+\left( \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3} \right)^2+\left( \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6} \right)^2+\left( \frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{10} \right)^2+\dots$$

I have no idea how to start. Any hint would be really appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%28sum+1%2Fi%2C+i+from+n%28n-1%29%2F2+%2B+1+to+n%28n%2B1%29%2F2%29%5E2%2C+n+from+1+to+inf) doesn't actually know.

Comment: I believe it's equal to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(H_{\frac{\left(n+1\right)n}{2}}-H_{\frac{n\left(n-1\right)}{2}}\right)^{2}$, where $H_n$ is the $n$th harmonic number.

Comment: @Jam Since $H_k$ has no exact form, can we say the given summation has no exact form too?

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari I don't think that logic really works since sometimes combinations can have a closed-form, despite the individual parts not having one. But I also think this series probably won't have one.

Answer (score 16):

Notice, that:

$$\left(\frac{1}{1}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}\right)^2 + \dots<\left(\frac{1}{1}\right)^2+\left(\frac{2}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2+\left(\frac{4}{7}\right)^2=2+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{n}{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+1}\right)^2<2+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2}{n-1}\right)^2$$

Since it's bounded by converging series, it's convergent itself.

Comment: Clear from your answer, that the series converges. Thanks for sharing your answer. What about its closed form? Is it possible to be found?

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari no problem. I tried to find an analytic solution, to no avail. I would stick to other comments/answers - I doubt there is one.

Answer (score 4):

**Approximation with Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula**

The Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula gives the fairly well-known asymptotic series for the Harmonic Numbers
$$
\begin{align}
H_n
&=\gamma+\log(n)+\frac1{2n}-\frac1{12n^2}+\frac1{120n^4}\\[3pt]
&-\frac1{252n^6}+\frac1{240n^8}-\frac1{132n^{10}}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^{12}}\right)\tag1
\end{align}
$$
where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant. $\gamma$ doesn't actually come from the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula, but is defined as $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(H_n-\log(n))$.

Substituting into $(1)$ and expanding Taylor series gives
$$
\begin{align}
\left(H_{n(n+1)/2}-H_{n(n-1)/2}\right)^2
&=\frac4{n^2}-\frac{16}{3n^4}+\frac{32}{45n^6}+\frac{1424}{315n^8}\\[3pt]
&+\frac{3392}{1575n^{10}}-\frac{112912}{10395n^{12}}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^{14}}\right)\tag2
\end{align}
$$
Equation $(2)$ not only shows that the series converges, but applying the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula to $(2)$ results in
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=1}^n\left(H_{k(k+1)/2}-H_{k(k-1)/2}\right)^2\\
&=C-\frac4n+\frac2{n^2}+\frac{10}{9n^3}-\frac8{3n^4}+\frac{398}{225n^5}+\frac{16}{45n^6}-\frac{4378}{2205n^7}\\[3pt]
&+\frac{712}{315n^8}-\frac{22718}{14175n^9}+\frac{1696}{1575n^{10}}+\frac{138}{4235n^{11}}-\frac{56456}{10395n^{12}}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^{13}}\right)\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Plugging $n=200$ into $(3)$ gives
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(H_{k(k+1)/2}-H_{k(k-1)/2}\right)^2=3.170466061427153684757796531}\tag4
$$
As a check, $n=300$ gives the same result.

Comment: Great! Thank you. I am still believing that the series has a closed form, possibly includes $\pi, e, \ln( ), \dots$. I will still try. Thanks again (+1)

Comment: Hopefully, this approximation can help in verification of a closed form. Unfortunately, the [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html) does not find anything obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Since for moderately large values of $n$ we have
$$ H_n \approx \log(n)+\gamma+\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{12n^2} $$
we also have
$$ H_{n(n+1)/2}-H_{n(n-1)/2} \approx \frac{2}{n}-\frac{4}{3n^3}$$
and
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\left[H_{n(n+1)/2}-H_{n(n-1)/2}\right]^2 \approx 1+\sum_{n\geq 2}\left(\frac{2}{n}-\frac{4}{3n^3}\right)^2=1+\frac{2 \left(-1890+2835 \pi ^2-252 \pi ^4+8 \pi ^6\right)}{8505} $$
is finite and approximately equal to $\color{green}{3.17}151$. I doubt there is a simple closed form.

Comment: Using the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula, I get $3.1704660614271536848$

Answer (score 1):

#### Suggestion.

This is merely a suggestion that is too large to fit in a comment. Euler's integral formula for the harmonic numbers, $H_n=\int_0^1\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}\ \mathrm{d}x$, gives us a formula for the series as $a\to1^-$:

$$S=4\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[f_a(n(n+1))-f_a(n(n-1))\right]^2$$

where $f_a(x)=\int_{0}^{a}\frac{t^{x+1}}{1-t^{2}}\ \mathrm{d}t$. The function, $f_a$, can also be given in terms of the hypergeometric function, as $\frac{a^{x+2}}{x+2}\cdot{_2F}_1\left(1,\frac{x}2+1;\frac{x}2+2;a^{2}\right)$.

Thus, it could potentially aid in finding an analytic solution to $S$ (or showing whether that would be impossible) by finding a closed form for the square of the difference of hypergeometric functions, $\left[f_a(n(n+1))-f_a(n(n-1))\right]^2$. However, no such solution has leapt out to me so far.